# Перемножить значения внутри списков ячеек датафрейма

Tags: python, pandas, list

Можно ли обойтись без циклов и доп. библиотеки math что б перемножить значения внутри списков? В колонках asks и bids нужно перемножить левое число на правое и применить фильтр >30.Так же подскажите почему метод dt.time добавляет нули к миллисекундам, можно ли убрать нули или вообще оставить только время с точностью до секунды?

```
import pandas as pd
import math

# не переносить столбцы в консоли
pd.options.display.expand_frame_repr = False
arr_asks = []
arr_bids = []
all_amount = []
data = {'action': 'snapshot',
        'arg': {'channel': 'books5', 'instId': 'DCKUSDT', 'instType': 'SPOT'},
        'data': [{'asks': [['0.05040', '34.09'],
                           ['0.05045', '210.31'],
                           ['0.05064', '34.09'],
                           ['0.05075', '31.00'],
                           ['0.05077', '70.02']],
                  'bids': [['0.05008', '7749.89'],
                           ['0.05007', '199.72'],
                           ['0.04992', '635.05'],
                           ['0.04991', '70.02'],
                           ['0.04984', '93.42']],
                  'checksum': 0,
                  'ts': '1707929251792'}],
        'ts': 1707929251792}
df = pd.json_normalize(data, 'data', 'arg')
df['arg'] = df['arg'].str['instId']
asks = df['asks']
bids = df['bids']
for i in asks[0]:
    for j in i:
        fl = float(j)
        arr_asks.append(fl)
        if len(arr_asks) == 2:
            elem = math.prod(arr_asks)
            arr_asks.clear()
            all_amount.append(elem)
for i in bids[0]:
    for j in i:
        fl = float(j)
        arr_bids.append(fl)
        if len(arr_bids) == 2:
            elem = math.prod(arr_bids)
            all_amount.append(elem)
            arr_bids.clear()
df1 = (pd.DataFrame(all_amount,
                    columns=['amount'])
       .assign(Time_ms=df.iloc[0]['ts'], Ticker=df.iloc[0]['arg'])).query('amount >30')
df1['Time_ms'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Time_ms'],unit='ms').dt.time
print(df1)
```

результат должен быть такой:

```
       amount          Time_ms   Ticker
5  388.114491  16:47:19.552     DCKUSDT
7   31.701696  16:47:19.552     DCKUSDT
```

или такой:

```
amount          Time_ms   Ticker
5  388.114491  16:47:19     DCKUSDT
7   31.701696  16:47:19     DCKUSDT
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. "Взрываем" списки списков в столбцах 'asks', 'bids' - получаем несколько строк со списками по 2 элемента. Предположил, что списки в 'asks', 'bids' одинаковой длины, поэтому "взорвал" синхронно. Далее преобразуем 'asks', 'bids' во фреймы, чтобы получить по 2 столбца, их переводим во float и перемножаем и сохраняем обратно как 'asks', 'bids'. После чего, чтобы выбрать из двух столбцов >30, "расплавляем" (melt) фрейм и фильтруем. Выбираем нужные столбцы и печатаем.
2. Доли секунд обнуляем `dt.floor('s')`.
3. При преобразовании ts обратите внимание на *FutureWarning: The behavior of 'to_datetime' with 'unit' when parsing strings is deprecated. In a future version, strings will be parsed as datetime strings, matching the behavior without a 'unit'. To retain the old behavior, explicitly cast ints or floats to numeric type before calling to_datetime.*. Но если перевести ts предварительно в числовой тип `pd.to_numeric(df['ts'])`, получается не `16:47:19`, а `16:47:31`

```
df = pd.json_normalize(data, 'data', 'arg')
df['Ticker'] = df['arg'].str['instId']
df['Time_ms'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ts'], unit='ms').dt.floor('s').dt.time
df = df.explode(['asks', 'bids'], ignore_index=True)
df[['asks', 'bids']] = df[['asks', 'bids']].apply(lambda x: pd.DataFrame(x.tolist()).astype(float).prod(axis=1))
df = df.melt(id_vars=['Ticker', 'Time_ms'], value_vars=['asks', 'bids'], value_name='amount').query('amount>30')[['amount', 'Time_ms', 'Ticker']]
print(df)
```

```
       amount   Time_ms   Ticker
5  388.114491  16:47:19  DCKUSDT
7   31.701696  16:47:19  DCKUSDT
```

Comment: спасибо буду разбираться

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете средствами pandas выполнить функцию на двух колонках, например перемножение двух колонок выглядит так:

```
def f(x):    
  return x[0]*x[1] 

df.apply(f, axis=1)
```

Comment: нужно перемножить не две колонки, а числа внутри списков состоящих из двух элементов межу собой т.е. :'data': [{'asks': [['0.05040', '34.09'],    '0.05040'* '34.09'
                           ['0.05045', '210.31'],  '0.05045'* '210.31'
                           ['0.05064', '34.09'],    '0.05064'*'34.09'
                           ['0.05075', '31.00'],   '0.05075'* '31.00'
                           ['0.05077', '70.02']],  '0.05077'*'70.02' тожесамое и для колонки bids

Comment: В функции которую вы применяете к каждой строке - вы можете перемножать что угодно, список находящийся в колонке будет доступен под соответствующим индексом, содержимое первой колонки - x[0] и там вы уже разбиваете на элементы список содержащийся в этой ячейке и перемножаете